# How to correctly send php variables through ng-click parameters

Tags: php, angularjs

Currently i'm trying to send a time and a date from php to my angular controller by using a ng-click.

```
$time is a date
$today is a datetime
```

Can someone explain me why this works

```
<button ng-click="getClickInfo('<?php echo $time; ?>', '<?php echo $today; ?>')";</button>
```

But when i try to achieve the same result within an echo like this, it gives me different and incorrect output

```
<?php echo '<button ng-click="getClickInfo(' . $time . ', ' . $today . ')";></button>'; ?>
```

I tried to search on the internet for a solution but i couldn't really find a topic about it. Hope someone can explain me what is happening in this scenario. Redirection to any articles on this topic would be really helpfull for me.

Output:

```
01:00 // incorrect output
01/01/1970 // incorrect output

20.30 // desired output
22-04-2016 // desired output
```

Comment: Your html string is not correct. It should be: '<button ng-click="getClickInfo(' . $time . ', ' . $today . ')"></button>' I can't say for sure that is your exact issue, but for correct HTML, that needs to be fixed

Comment: Fixed the html string but still returns me the same incorrect result

Comment: I see that the quotes are missing if i inspect my code, but i still have no idea if there is a fix for it. Example one (correct example) is like ('20.30', '22-04-2016'), example two is like (20.30, 22-04-2016). This probably is causing the problem.

Comment: why to use php and angular together ? angular views should get there data from $scope. this $scope should be initialised in controllers side (with http query for example ).

Comment: Good question, i already had made a php class that renders certains dates and times for a calender. I've used more php than angular yet, but now i read your comment it seems obvious for me to remake those php functions as angular functions for best practice. I simply miss some angular expierence yet i'm trying to obtain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to quote the javascript function arguments, otherwise you get unpredictable results
The ctach here is that the HTML `ng-click` attribute must be enclosed in double quotes and the attribute value (your function) must not contain double quotes, because it would break the HTML

Furthermore, the `;` is not needed, you're putting it outside the `ng-click` HTML attribute value, that is not valid HTML

Here's a fix, note that quotes are escaped with backslash inside PHP strings:

```
<?php echo '<button ng-click="getClickInfo(\'' . $time . '\', \'' . $today . '\')"></button>' ?>
```

Here's a more readable way to do it, I would recommend this approach:

```
<?php echo '<button ng-click="getClickInfo(' . "'$time', '$today'" . ')";></button>' ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was looking for something like this but i simply didn't know how to do it. This pretty much solved it.